# Understanding Callbacks

Tags: node.js

I am very confused when it comes to javascript callbacks... Especially when attempting to learn node at the same time.
You see, I understand the concept of passing a function as a parameter to another function but what confuses me mostly are the premade modules that "accept" callbacks functions.

For example a simple request looks like so:

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'http://www.google.com';

request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {

    if(error){
      console.log('This request resulted in an error', error);
    }
    console.log(body);
});
```

This get method accepts a url and a callback. 
Who defines that a callback is accepted? The developer of the specific method?
Also, the 3 parameters that we pass within the function (error, response, and body)... how does the request module know to populate these variables with data on return?

Comment: imo, with javascript learn about 'callbacks' or closures. With node.js then learn about `promises` as soon as possible. And only use callbacks in very limited circumstances. Or command chains may be useful? maybe interesting? http://stackabuse.com/avoiding-callback-hell-in-node-js/

Comment: @Query - If one of these answers below answered your question, then please indicate that by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the best answer.  If not, then please comment to each answer about what it did not yet answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine `get` implemented more or less like

```
function get(url, callback) {
    var response = they somehow retrieve the response;
    var body = they somehow parse the body;
    var error = ...;

    // they call you back using your callback
    callback( error, response, body );
}
```

How these values are computed is irrelevant (this is their actual job) but then they just call you back assuming your function actually accepts three arguments in given order (if not you just get a runtime error).

In this sense they also kind of "accept" your callback by ... well, calling it back :) There is no worry about the number of arguments as Javascript is very "forgiving" - methods can be called with any number of arguments, including less or more arguments than the function expects.

Take this as an example:

```
// they provide 3 arguments
function get( callback ) {
   callback( 0, 1, 2 );
}

// but you seem to expect none
get( function() {
});
```

The `get` assumes that the callback accepts three arguments while I pass a method that supposedly doesn't accept **less** arguments. This works, although the three arguments, `0`, `1` and `2` are not bound to any formal callback arguments (you can't directly refer to them), they are there in the `arguments` object, an array-like structure:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Take another example

```
function get( callback ) {
   callback( 0, 1, 2 );
}

get( function(a,b,c,d,e) {
});
```

This time the callback I pass seems to expect **more** arguments than the caller provides and still, no problem here. Arguments are bound to consecutive call parameters, `a` will get 0, `b` will get 1, `c` will get 2 and `d` and `e` will get `undefined` inside the callback body.

Both examples show that the caller doesn't really care how your callback is defined, whether its number of arguments matches the expectation or not. In case of any mismatch, the worst what could happen is a runtime error:

```
function get( callback ) {
   callback( 0, 1, 2 );
}

get( 1 );

// Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

> This get method accepts a url and a callback. Who defines that a callback is accepted? The developer of the specific method?

Yes. The author(s) of `request.get()` defined it specifically to expect and make use a "callback" function.

You can define your own functions to accept callbacks as well, especially useful when they depend on other asynchronous functions – such as `setTimeout()` for a simple example.

```
function delay(value, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // this statement defines the arguments given to the callback
        // it specifies that only one is given, which is the `value`
        callback(value);
    }, 1000);
}

delay('foo', function (value) { // named to match the argument `delay` provides
    console.log(value);
});
```

> Also, the 3 parameters that we pass within the function (error, response, and body)... how does the request module know to populate these variables with data on return?

The arguments given and their order are part of `request`'s definition, same as `delay()` above defining that `(value)` would be the argument(s) for its `callback`.

When providing a callback, the parameters only give the arguments names for you own use. They have no effect on how the main function (`request.get()`, `delay()`, etc.) behaves.

Even without naming any parameters, `request.get()` is still passing the same 3 arguments in the same order to the callback:

```
request.get(url, function () { // no named parameters
    var error = arguments[0];  // still the 1st argument at `0` index
    var body = arguments[2];   // still the 3rd argument at `2` index

    if(error){
        console.log('This request resulted in an error', error);
    }
    console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The designer of a function/method decides what arguments it will accept and process.  So, if a function accepts a callback as an argument, then it is the design and implementation of the function that decided that and will call the callback at the appropriate time.

It is also the implementer of the function/method that decides what arguments will be passed to the callback when it is called.  What confuses many people is that is is the caller of the function that defines the callback function itself that will be called by the main function/method.  But the arguments of the callback function MUST be declared to match what the main function/method will pass to the callback.  The labels given to the arguments when you define the callback are merely labels for programming convenience (as a means of referring to the arguments by name).  How the callback's arguments are defined in the callback function has nothing to do with what is actually passed to the callback - that is all decided by the function/method that calls the callback.  So, when you use `request.get()`, the contract for using it is that it accepts a callback that should be declared to have the arguments `(error, response, body)` because that's what it will be called with.  Now, it is OK to leave off arguments at the end if you aren't going to use them (they will still be there, but you just won't have a convenient name to refer to them by), but you can't leave off arguments before any that you intend to use because order is important.

> Who defines that a callback is accepted? The developer of the specific
>   method?

Yes, the developer of the function/method decides if a callback is accepted.

> Also, the 3 parameters that we pass within the function (error,
>   response, and body)... how does the request module know to populate
>   these variables with data on return?

The `request.get()` method is programmed to pass three arguments `(error, response, body)` to its callback and that's what it will pass.  No matter how the callback itself is actually declared, `request.get()` will pass these three arguments in that order.  So, what confuses many people is that the caller of the function/method creates the callback function itself and gets to define the arguments for it.  Well, not really.  The creator of the callback must create a callback that **matches** the contract the the function/method is expecting.  If it doesn't match the contract, then the callback likely won't function properly as it will get confused about what it was passed.  Really the contract here is that the first argument to the callback will be an `error` value and if that value is not truthy, then the next two arguments will be `response` and `body`.  Your callback must match that contact in order to use those arguments correctly.  Because Javascript is not strictly typed, it will not be a run-time error if you declare your callback incorrectly, but your access to those arguments will likely be wrong - causing things to work incorrectly.

For example, if you declared your callback to be:

```
function myCallback(response, body, err) { .... }
```

Then, what your callback sees as `response` would actually be the `error` value because `request.get()` put the error value in the first argument, no matter how the callback itself is declared.

Another ways of seeing this is to define a callback with no defined parameters and then access them entirely with the `arguments` object.

```
function myCallback() {
    console.log(arguments[0]);    // err value
    console.log(arguments[1]);    // response value
    console.log(arguments[2]);    // body value
}
```

The same is true of the return value in the callback.  If you are using `Array.prototye.map()`, it expects a callback that is passed three arguments and returns a new array element.  Even though you are implementing the callback, you must define a callback that is compatible with that contract.